Is it possible to override package path of Maven dependency?
In my Maven project i use jaxb2-maven-plugin which uses com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom dependency. The problem is that from version 2.2.11 of rngom the package org.kohsuke.rngom was moved to com.sun.tools.rngom. I can no longer use 2.2.11 as dependency for vulnerability reasons.
If i am using a superrior version than 2.2.11 of com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom i have build error, because the classes are no longer in package : org.kohsuke.rngom but in com.sun.tools.rngom.
Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.(BGMBuilder.java:147) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:117)
  at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:407)
  at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:162) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:117) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:354) at
  org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:468)
  at
  org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:315)
  at
  org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
  at
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305) at
  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192) at
  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) at
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972) at
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293) at
  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196) at
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102) ... 30 more Caused
  by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindGreen.(BindGreen.java:65) ...
  35 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at
  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102) ... 36 more Caused
  by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kohsuke/rngom/nc/NameClass at
  com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ct.ComplexTypeFieldBuilder.(ComplexTypeFieldBuilder.java:66)
  ... 41 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.kohsuke.rngom.nc.NameClass at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
  at
  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
  ... 42 more

How could i fix this dependency problem ?

You might be able to pull something off using the approaches to create fat/uber jars, e.g. class relocation. However, this might cause other problems
as class interfaces, method signatures etc. might not be compatible or keys used for reflection might not be updated. It would be best to try and upgrade the normal way.

The error you get indicates you're using an old version of another dependency, e.g. of plexus-classworlds (which would contain SelfFirstStrategy). Updating these dependencies to be compatible with a newer version of the plugin would be the more prudent approach.

i have tried adding the most recent version of the "plexus-classworlds" dependency , but it throws the same error.

Which version of the plugin are you using ? You need jaxb2.2 support ?

i am using org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin v2.5.0 and com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom v3.0.2

org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin v2.5.0 is getting com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom v2.3.7 from transitive dependency of jaxb-xjc v2.3.7. Why would you get v3.0.2 ? (It's JakartaEE9 version of rngom, which could be incompatible with jaxb 2.3 JavaEE8)

I have resolved the problem. I had t oupdate jaxb-xjc version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.2 and rngom to 2.3.3. It was confusing because jaxb-xjc dependency was never mentioned in build errors. What i learned is that you have to check the minimal requirements of the dependency chain.

I have resolved the problem. I had to oupdate jaxb-xjc version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.2 and rngom to 2.3.3. It was confusing because jaxb-xjc dependency was never mentioned in build errors.
You have to check minimal version requirement one by one in the dependency chain :
plugin 2.5.0 has minimal requirement of jaxb-xjc v2.3.2 and jaxb-xjc has minimal requirement of rngom v2.3.2. Update all of the chain to minimal requirements.
